# More than one navigation menu in DjangoCMS

Tags: django, django-cms

I got a task to make **two navigation menus** on a site:

1. 'Main' menu ("About", "Contacts", etc)
2. Catalogue menu ("Projects", "Gallery 1", "Gallery 2" etc)

I know that I could use something django-sitetree - but it is pretty complicated to give it to the customer :(

How can I do it via Django CMS?

**upd:**

Seem that the best thing is to make two 'folders' that just won't be shown in navigation (there is  a special checkbox for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django-cms has it's own built in menu system.
For example this snippet will load a full menu. Pages and subpages.

```
{% load menu_tags %}
<ul>
    {% show_menu 0 100 100 100 %}
</ul>
```

You should read this page here to see all the different menus you can get from django-cms. 
[django-cms navigation](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.3/getting_started/navigation.html)
And all the work is done for you!

If you have a custom app and would like to build up a menu yourself then that too is very easy. The best is to read this page, even copy paste this code and put in your own stuff.
[Custom app menus](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.3/extending_cms/app_integration.html)

Comment: Thank you, but this is not exactly what I am looking for. I understand the navigation system, but the problem is that it is rendered from one root. What do I need to do if i want 2 different menus? Am I just to create 2 chldren in the root and render each one's menu?

Comment: @ns-keip will the menus be dynamic or static? If dynamic following page structure of the CMS then I your idea of have 2 root parents and building off there. If one or both menus are static then perhaps just build up your own menus.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a page with meta "catalogue".
2. Hide the page in navigation (use cms for that)
3. Create subpages "Projects", "Gallery 1", "Gallery 2" for page "catalogue"
4. Use show_menu_below_id tag with meta "catalogue" to show your catalogue menu in template
5. Use main menu as usual

That's working for me, hope it will be helpfull for you